# Issue About JS and Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to shrink header and i nailed it but when i click on a nav item "projects" section doesn't get the class name from JS script until i scroll. Here's my code.

Website: [https://yigitceli.github.io][1]

Here everything is working correctly except "project" nav item. When I inspect items from browsers, after i click and before i scroll i noticed that "project" nav item doesn't get the classes from js. I think problem is in the JS script.

Edit: I noticed that now at the start of website "project" nav item or "contact" nav item randomly get the class name from javascript.

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 30) {
    var navItems = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-items");
    for (let i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
      navItems[i].className = "nav-items2";
    } 
    var navs = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-list");
    for (let i = 0; i < navs.length; i++) {
      navs[i].className = "nav-list2";
    }
    document.querySelector("h1").classList.add("h1");
    document.querySelector("header").id = "header2";
  } else {
    var navs = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-list2");
    for (let i = 0; i < navs.length; i++) {
      navs[i].className = "nav-list";
    }
    var navItems = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-items2");
    for (let i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
      navItems[i].className = "nav-items";
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("h1")[0].classList.remove("h1");
    document.getElementById("header2").id = "";
  }
}
```

```css
h1 {
  width: 35%;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
.h1 {
  color: #807d78;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 65%;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-items {
  padding-left: 15%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
.nav-items2 {
  padding-left: 10%;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-list {
  color: seashell;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 1s ease-in;
}
.nav-list2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #807d78;
  transition: color 1s ease-in;
}
.nav-list:hover {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  border-bottom: 0.12em seashell solid;
}
.nav-list2:hover {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  border-bottom: 0.12em #807d78 solid;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <h1>Yiğit Balceli</h1>
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-items"><a class="nav-list" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="nav-items"><a class="nav-list" href="#project-rows">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="nav-items"><a class="nav-list" href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("h1")` is probably not what you meant; in the other portion of the code, you correctly use `.querySelector()` to get the `<h1>` element.

Comment: Also, *setting* the class string like that is a fragile coding practice. You'd be better off using `element.classList.add()` and `.remove()` to add and remove class strings.

Comment: Actually i have class named h1 but i didn't added in the post here but thanks for your advice.

Comment: i know and i tried to remove with "remove()" function however when i use it one of my nav items get classname for shrinking at the start of the web. I don't know why this problem occurs.